# Python equation solver (max and min)

Tags: python, sympy, equation

How can I resolve the equation like `x * max(x,15) = 10` with python (maybe Sympy) libraries?
The `max()` means the maximum between given two arguments.
My equations has a more complicated form, but I want to resolve it in simplified form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like SymPy can solve this equation if you convert the `Max` to a `Piecewise`.

```
In [4]: solve(x*Piecewise((x, x >=15), (15, x < 15)) - 10, x)
Out[4]: [2/3]
```

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich as you can see, multiline code doesn't work so well in a comment. Can you edit your question to include this, and the error that you are getting?

Comment: Do you know other method for solving this equation without Sympy? Maybe with numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 1):

When I plug your equation into `sympy.solve`, it gives NotImplementedError, meaning the algorithms to solve it are not implemented (I opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10158 for this).

I think to solve equations like these, you would need to replace each `Max` or `Min` with its arguments and solve every iteration, and then remove the solutions where the `Max` or `Min` was not actually maximal or minimal in its argument.

I'll leave the full algorithm to you or some other answerer (or hopefully someone will implement it in SymPy). Some useful tips:

- `expr.atoms(Max, Min)` will extract all instances of `Max` and `Min` from `expr`.
- `expr.subs(old, new)` will return a new expression with `old` replaced with `new` in `expr`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no answer to your equation. You are assigning `x=3`, so there is no variable to solve for.

```
x
3

Max(x, 15)
15

solve(x*Max(x, 15)-10, x) #No variable here
[]
```

Maybe, you meant to do this : 
`y*Max(x, 15) = 10`

Then it becomes a valid question.

```
In [1]: solve(y*Max(x, 15)-10, y)
Out[1]: [2/3]
```

Comment: Why I don't have an answer to this equation? The root is x = 10/15. I've found it by selection numbers. But I don't know how I can resolve it using python.

Comment: This is because `x` is assigned the value 3. So, `x*Max(x, 15)-10` is a scalar value, there is no variable to solve for.

Comment: Okay, you find `y`, but I want to find `x` value. In first step why you assign `x` to `3`, why don't you assign it to `1000000`?

Comment: Erm, you assigned `x=3` in the example present in your question. I just replicated that.

Comment: You could assign `x` to `2/3` at once and get right root. Of course, if you incorrectly assign `x` to `3`, you will get empty list of roots in `solve(x*Max(x, 15)-10, x)`. Because `3` isn't root of equation.

Comment: Precisely. Do you now see where you made a mistake in your question ?

Comment: `y*Max(x, 15) = 10` is a different equation from `x*Max(x, 15) = 10`. It happens to have the same answer in `y` because the answer is found by choosing `15` in the `Max`.

Comment: @asmeurer, the OP assigned a value to `x`. (`x=3`). How is it still a equation ? If one does not assign `x=3`, SymPy complains it cannot solve the equation (`NotImplemented`).

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary I didn't see the image that was in the original equation, which appears to have been removed. Even so, the two variable equation with x and y is different from the one variable equation with x.

Comment: @asmeurer Indeed. The OP originally assigned `x=3` and so there was no variable to solve for. Hence, my suggestion.